# Unable to build the Android module using Appcelerator SDK 5.2.0.GA

Tags: module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have downloaded an existing android module from GitHub and while trying to build it using 5.2.0.GA, I am getting the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED /Users/soumya/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.0.GA/module/android/build.xml:348: The following error occurred while executing this line: /Users/soumya/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.0.GA/module/android/build.xml:303: exec returned: 2
```

Has anyone faced such issue while building their module with 5.2.0.GA?

Comment: which module are you trying to compile?

Comment: It is a google analytics module. The issue is that I have created  a new project and copied the .java file and removed the exampleproxy.java file. But while building, it says exampleproxy has the same functions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 303 is the check for Android NDK. Do you have it installed and your build.properties are correct?

e.g.

```
titanium.platform=/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/5.2.0.GA/android
android.platform=/home/user/tools/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-21
google.apis=/home/user/tools/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-21
android.ndk=/home/user/tools/android-ndk
```

I've tested it with a different module (5.1.2 and 5.2.0) and it doesn't give me the error.

Comment: Thanks. I did not have the android.ndk property defined in the build.properties file. Once that had been mentioned, it is working fine.